# How to inject HTTP client from library in Micronaut app?

Tags: kotlin, micronaut, micronaut-client

I have an external http client to other service and I've imported it to my micronaut app but receives an error which points:

> Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [xxx.files.client.micronaut.FilesClient] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).

I've added these classes when the app starts:

```
object TransformerApplication {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        Micronaut.build()
                .packages(
                        "xxx.transformer",
                        "xxx.files.client.micronaut"
                )
                .mainClass(TransformerApplication.javaClass)
                .start()
    }
}
```

But when creating:

```
@KafkaListener("transformer-group")
class EventsConsumerImpl(private val xlsTransformer: XlsTransformer,
                         private val filesClient: FilesClient,
                         private val workspacesClient: WorkspacesClient) : EventsConsumer {
    ...
    }
```

My http-client:

````
@io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client("\${files.url}")
interface FilesClient {

    companion object {
        const val FILES_TOKEN_KEY = "FILES"
    }

    @FilesTokenVerification
    @Get("\${files.url}/{fileId}")
    fun getFile(@PathVariable fileId: String): ByteArray

    @FilesTokenVerification
    @Patch("\${files.url}/{fileId}/info")
    fun updateFileStatus(@PathVariable fileId: String, @Body metadata: Metadata): Metadata

    @FilesTokenVerification
    @Get("\${files.url}/{fileId}/info")
    fun getFileMetadata(@PathVariable fileId: String): Metadata
}```

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?
````

Answer (score 0):

is usuallay use a factory for that:

https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#factories

but i do not know if that works with declarative clients.
Maybe try a wrapper around.